# Calculate max flow of the network

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization, graph-algorithm, max-flow, network-flow

Can anyone help to calculate max flow of this network and cuts in this network [Network diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMlr0.png) as according to me max Flow from s to t is 4 and my teacher it is 6 !

Comment: What is a max flow ? Are the values the flow ? The max flow between which nodes ? Is the max flow the max of the min flow in each possible paths ? The answer depends on which two nodes you consider. Between u and v, the max flow is 6. If the max is between any pairs of nodes, the answer is 6.

Comment: max flow from s to t these are the values are the capacities

Comment: s is a source node it can generate infinite flow and t is sink it absorb all flow but want to calculate ,how much you can flow maximum at anytime?

Comment: Now I see. I would also say that the maximum flow is 4. The maximum flow through u is 2, and the maximum flow through v is also 2. The flow to t is the sum which is 2. The capacity of link between v and t is the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

You would be right; using [`scipy.sparse.csgraph.maximum_flow`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.maximum_flow.html):

```
>>> from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
>>> from scipy.sparse.csgraph import maximum_flow
>>> m = csr_matrix([[0, 2, 4, 0], [0, 0, 6, 4], [0, 0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0]])
>>> maximum_flow(m, 0, 3)
MaximumFlowResult with value of 4
```